# Status of the Loading the TextureAtlas

Tags: java, android, libgdx, texture-atlas

I am using the TextureAtlas in my LibGdx based game. As the size of the Atlas increases the loading time increases hence there is a delay in showing the animations that I have setup in the game.

Hence I wish to get the status of the loading process of my TextureAtlas. 
1. Anyway to get the status ?
2. Any Listener ?

Answer (score 0):

You can take for example, asset that have been loaded with this method, `yourAssetManage.getLoadedAssets ()` this method return an `int` *indicating the number of loaded assets*

```
    Gdx.app.log("asset loaded :", ""+yourAssetManger.getLoadedAssets());

    if (yourAssetManger.update()) {

         if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) { 
            yourGame.setScreen(new yourScreen());
        }
    }
```

or isLoaded(String fileName); http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/assets/AssetManager.html#isLoaded-java.lang.String-

```
yourAssetManage.isLoaded("fileNameOfYourAsset");
```